# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance, dynamic form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making a dynamic form using [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) but I'm a little bit confused, the form is in a dialog made with angular materials.

modal-admin-cops.component.html

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Title</h2>
<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <ng-container class="form-row" *ngFor="let item of intData">
            <app-input-field [formGroup]="formGroup"
                            [data]="item.data" 
                            [controlName]="item.controlName" 
                            [placeHolder]="item.placeHolder" 
                            *ngIf="item.input==='inputField'">
            </app-input-field>
            <!--
            <app-file-field [form]="form"
                        [data]="item" 
                        [controlName]="item.controlName" 
                        [placeHolder]="item.placeHolder" 
                        *ngIf="item.input==='fileField'">

            </app-file-field>
            <app-select-field [form]="form"
                            [data]="item" 
                            [controlName]="item.controlName" 
                            [placeHolder]="item.placeHolder" 
                            *ngIf="item.input==='selectField'">
            </app-select-field>
            -->
        </ng-container>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" [mat-dialog-close]="data" (click)="save()">Publish</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

modal-admin-cops.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-admin-cops',
  templateUrl: './modal-admin-cops.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-admin-cops.component.css']
})
export class ModalAdminCopsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private controllerNames:string[]=[];
  private intData;
  private formGroup:FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private renderer:Renderer2,
    private http:HttpClient,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dialogRef:MatDialogRef<ModalAdminCopsComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:any[]) 
    {
      this.intData=data;
      this.cargar();
    }
  cargar(){
    this.intData.forEach(x=>{
      console.log(x.data);
      if(x.input==="inputField"){
        this.controllerNames.push(x.controlName);
      }
    });

    console.log(this.controllerNames);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("llega");
    this.formGroup=this.toFormGroup();
    console.log(this.formGroup);
  }
  toFormGroup():FormGroup{
    let group:any;
    this.controllerNames.forEach(x=>{
      group[x]=new FormControl();
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
  save(){
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

The `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:any[])` receives something like this:

```ts
[{
   input:"inputField",
   controlName:"nombre",
   placeHolder:"Escribe el nombre de la cop",
   data:{
     cod:here goes a number,
     desc:Here goes a string
  }
}]
```

Sometimes data maybe an array of {cod,desc}

input-field.component.html

```html
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <mat-form-field #input class="expand" [class]="placeHolder">
                <input matInput
                        [(value)]="data.desc"
                        [placeholder]='placeHolder' 
                        [formControlName]='controlName'>
        </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

input-field.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-field',
  templateUrl: './input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-field.component.css']
})
export class InputFieldComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() formGroup:FormGroup;
  @Input() data:any;
  @Input() controlName:string;
  @Input() placeHolder:string;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

When I click a button that start the dialog I get this:

```
ModalAdminCopsComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
InputFieldComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

What I am trying to do is to create the form dynamically with different types of inputs.

Edit1: 
If i used:

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this.formGroup=this.toFormGroup();
  console.log(this.formGroup);
}
```

I get:

```
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

If I used:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.formGroup=this.toFormGroup();
  console.log(this.formGroup);
}
```

i get:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
Cannot set property 'nombre' of undefined
```

Comment: Does it work if you add a condition to check if formgroup exist ? `<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="formGroup">`. If not, can you please show what return `console.log(this.formGroup);` after it was builded ?

Comment: @Angular It doesnt work, because the form doesnt fill.
And the console.log doesnt print anything. The only one that prints something is the ones that is before this.toFormGroup()

Comment: Would you make a stackblitz ? It look like you are building the form too late but i'm not sure.

Comment: This is my assumption but you're instantiating `formGroup` too late, `formGroup` will be undefined if you instantiat it inside `ngAfterViewInit` so when rendering the forms and `formGroup` is called, the type won't match, you need to instantiate `formGroup` before the form renders, switch `ngAfterViewInit` for `OnInit`.

Comment: I get also some error, i edit my answer so you can see what errors i get.
@Angular Im unable to reproduce it con stackblitz, i get errors on importing modules to app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a get a way to add the controllers:
I put this in the input.component.ts

```ts
ngOnInit(){
  this.formGroup.controls[this.controlName]=new FormControl();
}
```

That seems to add to the formGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your formGroup in the constructor or in ngInit

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: new FormControl('')
});
```

Comment: It works halfway. It stops saying that there is no formgroup, but says that there is not control with name:"name"

Comment: You need to add all your form controls while initializing. Edited answer for the control name

Comment: What i get its the error that i post above.Cannot set property 'nombre' of undefined

Comment: You are trying to set 'nombre' to formGroup before initiating it

Comment: I tried to do in ngOnInit and the constructor as you said. But i get de undefined set propoerty error.  I may put also in the input.field.ts ngOnInit() method?